# Possible to display days from DateTime objects in separate dropdown boxes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, forms, razor

What I have : A C# database query that returns two columns, one of which contains a start time of a meeting, the other of which contains the end time. The times are of the same time period and cannot be over two days.

What I would like to do : Cycle through these returned values, and create a dropdown box for each day containing the start-corresponding end time. If there are no values for a certain day, display the message "No times free for this day".

My code so far :

```
  var result = db.Query(//returns two columns, ds and de, two dateTimes meaning the start and end date of an event.)

<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="insert.cshtml">
    <label>@result.First().ds.DayOfWeek <select name="start_to_end_time"></label> 
        @foreach(var record in result) {
             if(day.Equals(record.ds.DayOfWeek)) {
                 <option value="@record.ds">@record.ds.ToString("HH:mm") - @record.de.ToString("HH:mm")</option>
                } else {
                    </select>
                    <label>@record.ds.DayOfWeek<select name="start_to_end_time"></label>
                    <option value=@record.ds>@record.ds.ToString("HH:mm") - @record.ds.ToString("HH:mm")</option>
                }  
        }
```

This throws the error : "Encountered end tag "select" with no matching start tag.  Are your start/end tags properly balanced?"

However, looking at my code, I believe they are balanced correctly? Can anybody help me with this please?

Comment: I have figured out how to remove the error. I put the select tag into the @Html.Raw("") tag. However, my code never enters the second IF loop and all of the HTML is rendered incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the equivalent of this which is invalid markup:

```
<label> <select></label> 
</select>
```

Comment: My excuse is that it's late! Thanks very much :)